# Probe the output of "screen" every 30 minutes

Tags: raspberry-pi, gnu-screen, stdout

I have a program running in a "screen" session. It displays one line every 5 seconds to the console. I would like to "probe" this output twice every hour and initiate another program based on the content of the line.

How may I probe the screen session this way? I am on a Raspberry Pi and, ideally, would like to avoid writing to a file.

Edit: The process is already running.

Comment: One approach (if you can run again the process) is by piping your process to shell script or maybe redirect the output to named pipe (something similar to redirect to a file but with different behaviors). Or if you are already running the process then a workaround is by using `strace` or `gdb`

Comment: and if you need to pipe the output of your program into a script AND display it in screen, that's what [tee](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html#tee-invocation) is for.